# Create a task that takes up a specific amount of CPU and RAM

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, windows

I'm testing my company software project and would like to see how it works under heavy load conditions.
Is there anyway to create a task that takes up a big amount of CPU and only stops if I tell it to?
If it's not programmatically possible, what are other options? E.g. what software and input out there can quickly help me create such condition?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a web project? There are load testers available in that case.

Comment: @holdenweb: no it's not. It's a desktop app.

Comment: You can use some test tools to take it.

Comment: @RongNguyen: can you be more specific please? What's the name of the tools?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by program.

**For consuming CPU:**

A simple dead loop won't consume all the CPUs, because your CPU probably have multiple logical cores, so you need create multiple threads to do it. Here is the code:

```
DWORD WINAPI ConsumeSingleCore(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    DWORD_PTR mask = 1 << (int) lpThreadParameter;
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), mask);
    for (;;) {}
}

void ConsumeAllCores()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo = { 0 };
    ::GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors; ++i)
    {
        ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, ConsumeSingleCore, (LPVOID)i, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```

**For consuming memory:**

Allocating enough objects on the heap will be helpful, although it is not very accurate, because there will be some overhead caused by internal structures in system, like heap. If you need accurate number. I think using virtual memory directly will be a good choice. Here is the code:

```
void ConsumeRAM()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo = { 0 };
    ::GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    DWORD memSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    char *buffer = (char *)::VirtualAlloc(NULL, memSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Touch all the pages, so system will try to allocate physical memory for them.
    for (DWORD memAddrOffset = 0; memAddrOffset < memSize; memAddrOffset += systemInfo.dwPageSize)
    {
        buffer[memAddrOffset] = 0;
    }

    return;
}
```

And if you just need some tools to test, you could try [CPU overload](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-CPU-core-overload/index.html) for consuming certain number of cores and [MemAlloc](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-memalloc/index.html) for consuming certain number of memory.

Comment: Can you answer this part where it asks if it's programmatically possible?

Comment: Sure, I just added this part into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any simple loop will consume CPU, typically processes yield when they are waiting for the OS to do something, read disk, access network, allocate memory.

```
 int quiteBig = 20000;
 int a[quiteBig] ;

 while ( true ) {  // or check for a terminating condition

    for ( long  i = 0; i < quiteBig ; i++ ) {
           a[i] = i;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#:
For RAM

```
List<anyObject> hogger = new List<anyObject>();
for(long i = 0; i < someHugeNumber; i++)
    hogger.Add(new anyObject());
```

Basically try and see how many objects you need to take up the space you want.

For CPU

```
while(true)
    ;
```

That is an instant 100% CPU
If you want a bit less

```
while(true)
{
    for(long i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
    {
        ;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

with some number you can adjust the number of mad cycles before the break
=> Fiddle with the number for averaging down CPU usage

As termination for the `while`-loops you can use a button on a form or a key-combination or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is programmatically possible, as others have shown examples on how to load the CPU. Note that the CPU load generally only takes one core so you will need have a copy of the program running for each core (assign a script to each core and specify which core it will run on)

You could also look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing